# Installshield Primary Output Directory

Tags: wpf, installation, installshield

I am creating a Installshield installer for my WPF MEF application, all my projects are set to build to the same directory `MySolution\Bin`, but when adding the `Primary Output` from any project to my Installshield installer it uses the `MySolution\MyProject\x86\Debug`.

Is there a way for me to change the folder of the `Primary Output` files in a installer?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'how can I use the MySolution\MyProject\Release file path as the `Primary Output`', then just change your `Solution Platform` and `Solution Configurations` to the correct value in Visual Studio and build first:

[image]

Comment: No I do not want to use the release path, I want to use the default path that all my projects are being built to - '`MySolution\Bin`'.

Comment: Hmmm... sorry, I'm not sure about that. Any particular reason why you're building to that directory instead of the usual one?

Comment: I am using MEF to make the application pluggable and it is required that all assemblies are in on directory for composition.